# How to save result of query in csv file in client machine in oracle?

Tags: oracle, for-loop, export-to-csv

I write my queries on the client machine that is connected to a database on the server.
Sometimes I need to join some huge tables so I can't get my entire output at once and I run my query in a loop for smaller parts of data (for example for each city code) and then Aggregate the data.
Sometimes the query needs to run for hours and it leads to break the execution of query.
my question is:
Is there any way to add result of each part to a csv file in my queries and so if my query broke I run it for remaining parts?

The database is oracle and I use toad for oracle to run my queries.

Here is a simplified form of my query:

```
DECLARE 
TYPE br_data IS RECORD (brnchcod NUMBER, c100 NUMBER);
TYPE result IS TABLE OF br_data INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
bd br_data; 
rs result;
begin
     for cur_br in (select a.ABRNCHCOD from Afbranches a)
     loop
         Select 
             Br.ABRNCHCOD, Sum(K.CARD100)
         INTO bd
         From Afbranches Br
         Left Join 
         K
         On Br.ABRNCHCOD=K.ABRNCHCOD
         where Br.ABRNCHCOD = cur_br.ABRNCHCOD
         Group by Br.ABRNCHCOD;
         rs(rs.COUNT) := bd;
     end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line(bd.c100);
end;
```

Comment: you need to understand something. If you run a PLSQL block, the database can create a csv, but only in the server. ( for example, using UTL_FILE ). However, if you want to create the csv in client side, then you must change the logic and use SQL instead. I would do it in `sqlplus` applying some logic ( per branch ) using shell script. It is not complicated and it can be executed from client side

Answer (score 0):

dbms_output.put_line adds the string you pass to an array on the server (in your session's private area). Your tool should at the end read this array and print it's content. This is what tools like sqlplus do.

Now, if your query returns too many rows, this array can get well past the limits of your session's memory, and your connection can break, usually giving you an error. Sometimes the network will break your session without telling you (e.g. some firewalls have rules allowing them to break connections that are inactive after some minutes).
As the first commenter said, you are better off using just a SQL statement and getting the rows spooled to a file.